# Recursive movement on matrix

Tags: java, recursion, matrix

I'm Trying to write a recursive function that checks all possible paths in String Matrix to build a word, I can move only UP, DOWN, RIGHT & LEFT.
the function doesn't work and I don't understand why..

My Algorithm:
1. If Next step is valid:
1.1 Add next letter to the string
1.2 Check the cell as "Visited"(Stepped)
1.3 If the String is A word, print it.
2. Do the same for all the options for next step: right, left, up and down.

```
// Function to check if it is possible to go to position next
// from current position. The function returns false if next is
// not a valid position or it is already visited
public static boolean isValid(int x, int y, boolean[][] isStepped)
{
    int M = 4;
    int N = 4;
    return (x >= 0) && (x < M) &&
            (y >= 0) && (y < N) &&
            (!isStepped[x][y]);
}
public static void printWords(String A[][], int next_x, int next_j, boolean[][] isStepped, String s)
{
    if (isValid(next_x,next_j, isStepped)) // check if next step in bounds of array and not stepped already
    {
        s+=A[next_x][next_j]; // Add the valid letter to s
        isStepped[next_x][next_j] = true;
        if(isWord(s)) // check if the letters until now Constitute a word
        {
            System.out.println(s + " ");
        }
    }
    printWords(A, next_x+1, next_j, isStepped, s); // Move Up
    printWords(A, next_x-1, next_j, isStepped, s); // Move Down
    printWords(A, next_x, next_j+1, isStepped, s); // Move Right
    printWords(A, next_x, next_j-1, isStepped, s); // Move Left


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never reset a field to "false" in order to make it available for the next search. Once a field is used, it is never usable again.